# Wrap children content respectively to main parent width

Tags: css, flexbox

I wonder if there is a `flex-way` to create `fluid` like behaviour of the `parent` container: by moving red boxes n1 and n2 to the left of the blue box n3 and as a result moving the red box n3 to the left side of the container

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 525px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.child {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.blue .box {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red .box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child blue'>
    <div class='box'>1</div>
    <div class='box'>2</div>
    <div class='box'>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child red'>
    <div class='box'>1</div>
    <div class='box'>2</div>
    <div class='box'>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex tag : *Apache Flex [NOT CSS FLEXBOX]* --> please read tag description before using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:contents` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) on `.child` elements making the boxes behaving as they was child of the `.parent` element.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 555px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.child {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  display:contents
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.blue .box {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red .box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child blue'>
    <div class='box'>1</div>
    <div class='box'>2</div>
    <div class='box'>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='child red'>
    <div class='box'>1</div>
    <div class='box'>2</div>
    <div class='box'>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```